# Image information in iOS

Tags: ios, image, matrix, uiimageview, rgb

I'm wanting to save an image (*UIimageView*) as a matrix of RGB values in iOS. What is the best way to go about this?

To be clear I want each pixel in the image to correspond to a matrix from (0,0) to the maximum values of x and y.

Is there anyone who can provide information on getting RGB values from an image in iOS?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: im sorry I dont get it ... maybe.... see my 'answer' :D

Answer (score 0):

?

0,0,0, 0,0,1, 0,1,0 ... just increase 3 integers to 255 each

so e.g.

```
int r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
while(YES) {
   if(r<255) r++;
   else if(g<255) g++;
   else if(b < 255) b++;
   else break;

   //get uicolor for rgb and insert pixel into image
}
```

Comment: Hey,

Thanks for the answer. What I'm actually trying to do is save the rgb information about an image as a matrix.

So we have some image (UIImageview I guess), and I want to know what the rgb value of each pixel is from x,y origin to the maximum of x,y.

Hope that makes sense?